# Simpler formula for number of ways to pair up (or not ) $2n$ objects?

Tags: combinatorics

We can see that the number of ways to pair up $2n$ people is $(2n-1)!!$. But I want to calculate the number of ways to pair up those people where not necessarily all the people are paired. By summing over the possible numbers of pairs, we get a total of $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{2i}(2i-1)!!.$$ Is there a simpler version of this formula? Is there a simpler way to count these configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple closed form.  See [here](http://oeis.org/A000085) for some more information about the sequence.  If we let $a_n$ be given by your formula, we have the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}$.  There is also the generating function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^{x + x^2/2}.$$